# How do I find an inverse of any element in any group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuitionistic-logic, computer-assisted-proofs

I'm working on [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/), which is based on [intuitionistic type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory).
I defined groups in Agda with normal laws of groups, which (of course not only) says that there is an inverse element of every element of every group.

The question is, as I've defined, there **exists** such inverse, but how do I actually get that inverse? i.e. write a function $ inverse : G \to G $ where $ G $ is a group. Is it even possible? For example, given the group $ (\mathbb{Z}, +, 0) $, I want $ inverse(2) = -2 $.

Alternatively, can I prove $ inverse(inverse(a)) = a $ (or its equivalence) without such concrete $ inverse $ function?

Here is the Agda code:

```
data Sigma {l} (A : Set l) (B : A -> Set l) : Set l where
  _**_ : (a : A) -> B a -> Sigma A B

record Group {l} (G : Set l) (_op_ : G -> G -> G) (e : G) : Set l where
  field
    assoc : {a b c : G} -> (a op b) op c == a op (b op c)
    id : {a : G} -> e op a == a
    inv : {a : G} -> Sigma G (\a^-1 -> a^-1 op a == e)

_^-1 : forall {l} {G : Set l} {op : G -> G -> G} {e : G} {{inst : Group G op e}} -> G -> G
_^-1 {{inst}} a = ?
```

Comment: If you've interpreted "exists" with a dependent sum type, you can just project out the inverse element. I can't be too much more helpful without seeing the code.

Comment: I've added the source code.

Comment: Your Question is essentially about a [programming language, Agda,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)), but since it ask about how a mathematical operation (group inverses) can be expressed/implemented in that context, I'm inclined to treat it as on-topic.  However debugging help, even in such a context, is likely off-topic, and in any case cannot proceed without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  On the other hand your Question seems to allow for coding suggestions other than debugging.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want help about the mathematical notion? In which case you need to say what you mean by "find the inverse", what does it mean to "find" an element? Or do you want help with writing your code? In which case you asked on the wrong site.

Comment: @盛安安 Sorry, in my memory of that problem the group was finite, but that is not necessary and yes, this is true.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi "Finding the inverse" means writing a function $ inverse : G \to G $ mapping each element to its inverse where $ G $ is a group.

Comment: @rschwieb What is true?

Comment: Well here you go: $\operatorname{inverse}(x) = x^{-1}$. From a mathematical standpoint you can't say much more.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi If you are right, then the answer to my question is probably "no", but I also asked another question.

Comment: To be clearer, providing the fact that the triple $ (\mathbb{Z}, +, 0) $ is a group, I want to write a function where $ inverse(2) = -2 $ but I can not. I feel like I'm stuck somewhere where everyone else think is obvious.

Comment: I would consider making the inverse function part of the definition of a group, e.g. `record Group {l} (G : Set l) (_op_ : G -> G -> G) (_^-1 : G -> G) (e : G) : Set l`. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @yatima2975 Then my question would be, "Does it need to be so, no matter what?" :) It seems kinda strange to me, because intuitively _`^-1` can be determine from other parameters, but surely it's acceptable.

Comment: You can also determine the group's unit from the multiplication table, so why do you include that? The reason I advocate including the inverse is because that way you don't have to deal with existential quantification and/or prove uniqueness. This makes the group a [variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29) and generally easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively, can I prove $(a^{−1})^{−1}=a$ (or its equivalence) without such concrete inverse function?

Sure. The axioms of inversion, along with the axiom of identity allows you to prove the inverse of an element is unique.

If $ab=e$ for some element $b$, then $b=eb=a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}e=a^{-1}$.

Then since $a^{-1}(a^{−1})^{−1}=(a^{−1})^{−1}a^{-1}=e$, and also $a^{-1}a=aa^{-1}=e$, $a$ and $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ must be the same thing.

Comment: I can't even write down $ a^{-1} $ currently ... If I want to write it down rigorously, I need the function $ \square^{-1} $, but I haven't defined that function! I've merely prove its existence.

Comment: @盛安安 I was just answering your question in the tinted box. You can't "know" what the inverses of a group are until you specify what the operation is. I don't think I see that happening here. Surely you don't think there is a universal rule for finding inverses in any group (other than the one about knowing the operation)?

Comment: So, given an arbitrary binary operator, is there multiple ways of finding the inverse?

Comment: Can you find an example of a single binary operator having multiple possible inversion function? I know I've been too inquisitive but I promise I'll accept your answer if you answer this question in a promising way :)))

Comment: @盛安安  I don't understand what you're asking. Of course for a group, there is only one "inversion map." It is entirely dictated by the operation.

Comment: I've specified that operation.

Comment: @盛安安 It's probably because I have no idea how that code works, but I don't see any detail of what set or what operation your are using. I see what looks like a *schema* for defining the axioms of groups, but I don't see any operation. Defining a group and saying it has an operation and specifying a group are two different things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37466/discussion-between--and-rschwieb).